# Some swans (lived / were living) on the lake in the town last winter. "lived" vs "were living"

Tags: tense

Some swans (lived / were living) on the lake in the town last winter.

Recommended answer is "lived," but I think "were living" is better because the state of some swans living was very short. What do you think?

Comment: This always will depend on **what you want to say**, not on grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Both are good. In the absence of context, there is no way to choose between them. *Lived* is less specific.

As usual with aspectual distinctions, the difference is nothing to do with external circumstances (whether the swans' residence was short or long is irrelevant) and everything to do with how the speaker is choosing to present the temporal relationships.

If the speaker says "were living" they are choosing to present the event as a state which spread over a period; if they say "lived", they are not presenting it that way.

Comment: "were living" could express a temporary situation, they were living there last winter, but moved away in the spring. See: www.englishtenses.com

Comment: It could do, @anouk, but it doesn't necessarily. If, for example, I visited the lake often over a period of a few weeks, I might will say they "were living" there (implicitly, over the period when I was visiting).

Comment: _I might will say_ was a typo for _I might well say_, @VictorB. Stacked modals are not grammatical in most varieties of English (though they are in some).